# R igraph - visualize the network

Tags: r, igraph

I am trying to visualize network with products bought together. I am using R and library `igraph`. I have ~140 of nodes (products) and ~3200 edges (links between the products bought together plus number of occurencies of that particular combination - the weight).

In the end, I wish to show all products in network and connections between them, where the connection line's thickness (or maybe color) is based on number of occurences.

I have tried different types of network such as circle or Fruchterman-Reingold. But in the end it is all sort of clumped. Consider this example:

```
net <- graph_from_data_frame(d=edges, vertices=nodes, directed=T) 
net <- simplify(net, remove.multiple = F, remove.loops = T) 
plot(net, edge.arrow.size=.4,vertex.label=NA)
```

[image]

I think it is because the weights of edges have high variance (min:1, max:1647, avg: 52, st.dev: 110)

**How can I make it more readible?**

Comment: I haven't noticed any one size fits all answer to it. You need to increase the size of the plot and reduce the size of the vertices. It's kinda tricky,You basically have to play around with the plotting parameters. Try using `help(igraph.plotting)` to find what parameters you can change.

Comment: I have had the same problem and found the network plotting capabilities within igraph so clunky that I just do all the processing in R and plotting in Gephi or Cytoscape.

Comment: also recommend checking out R visNetwork package. You can start with an igraph and easily create a dynamic (js) plot where you can move nodes around as you like.

Comment: you can take the `log` of the edge weight so that the scale is more reasonable for visualization.